# Why does `which` print out a script?

Tags: zsh

`which conda` or  `which -a conda` prints out the content of  `conda.sh`, a script which chooses the conda executable and runs it, as (1) below.

I expect `which` to print the path of conda. That may or may not be this `conda.sh`, but in any case I don't expect to see the script's contents.

Simply running `conda` correctly prints out conda's help text, as (2) below.

The `PATH` correctly includes conda's directory  at the beginning, as  (3).

This is zsh on Mac.

(1)

```
conda () {
    if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]
    then
        "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA
    else
        \local cmd="$1"
        shift
        case "$cmd" in
            (activate | deactivate) __conda_activate "$cmd" "$@" ;;
            (install | update | upgrade | remove | uninstall) CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH="${PATH}"
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@"
                \local t1=$?
                PATH="${CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH}"
                if [ $t1 = 0 ]
                then
                    __conda_reactivate
                else
                    return $t1
                fi ;;
            (*) CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH="${PATH}"
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@"
                \local t1=$?
                PATH="${CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH}"
                return $t1 ;;
        esac
    fi
}
```

(2)

```
conda
usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...

conda is a tool for managing and deploying applications, environments and packages.

Options:

positional arguments:
  command
    clean        Remove unused packages and caches.
    compare      Compare packages between conda environments.
```

...

(3)

`/Users/user1/miniconda3/bin:/Users/user1/miniconda3/condabin:/Users/user1/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/user1/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/opt/terraform@0.13/bin:/Users/user1/.krew/bin:/Users/user1/bin:Library/Python/3.7/bin:/Users/user1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/munki:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/user1/executables:/Users/user1/go/bin:/Users/user1/executables/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/Users/user1/.local/bin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-p` flag:

```sh
% which pyenv 
pyenv () {
    local command
    command="${1:-}" 
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
    then
        shift
    fi
    case "$command" in
        (rehash | shell) eval "$(pyenv "sh-$command" "$@")" ;;
        (*) command pyenv "$command" "$@" ;;
    esac
}
% which -p pyenv
/usr/local/bin/pyenv
%
```

Note, though, that on Zsh, you can get more informative output by using the `whence` command:

```sh
% whence -aSv pyenv
pyenv is a shell function from /Users/marlon/.cache/zsh-snap/eval/pyenv-init.zsh
pyenv is /usr/local/bin/pyenv -> /usr/local/bin/../Cellar/pyenv/2.0.0/bin/pyenv -> /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/2.0.0/bin/../libexec/pyenv
%
```

---

The reason why you cannot find the `-p` flag in `man which`, is because in Zsh, `which` is a builtin command equivalent to `whence -c`:

```sh
% whence -aSv which
which is a shell builtin
which is /usr/bin/which
%
```

If you do `man which`, you get the manual for the *external* command `which` (on the second line in the output above). You can call the latter as follows:

```sh
% command which pyenv
/usr/local/bin/pyenv
%
```

The output of `whence` is more reliable, though. External command `which` only searches your `$path`, the result of which may or may not be what will be called when you type a command on the command line. `whence -aSv`, on the other hand, tells you exactly what will be called (the first line) and what alternatives there are.

For more info, consult the Zsh manual:

- [`whence`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-whence)
- [`which`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-which)

Comment: Thank you. I will try `whence` in future. Could you explain the `-p` switch? I do not see it with `man which` nor in various web pages like [this](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which)

Comment: @JoshuaFox I updated my answer to explain.

Comment: I see, so my confusion was because `which` is  here actually `whence`.

Comment: @MarlonRichert : Your explanation is really informative, but it does not explain why the OPs builtin _which_ would display the content of the script. For instance in my zsh, `which SCRIPT` just hows the absolute path of the script, not the content. Could the behaviour depend on the zsh version? I have 5.8.

Comment: @user1934428 OP's `conda` is not a script, but a _function._ Functions are loaded into memory. Scripts are not.

Comment: Ah, of course! I was confused a bit because the OP was using the word _script_, but the code posted clearly shows that it is a function.